# Dynamic Webpack file import during build time

Tags: webpack

I’m working on a browser extension that will have wrappers for browser APIs, I would like to be able to swap out browser-specific wrappers during build time.

I was told to use `process.env.NODE_ENV` 
and Webpack will drop branches of code that evaluate false, but I’m not exactly sure how/where to use it to achieve what I’m trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the DefinePlugin to your plugins array like so:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
 ...
 plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  }),
 ]
}
```

Comment: And I've seen those examples floating around. However my case is that I'm making an extension and I support one browser API via a set of files for Firefox and another set for Safari how to dynamically swap beween the file imports example "import Storage from 'api/firefox/storage';" and swap that for "import Storage from 'api/safari/storage';" I don't see how process.env.NODE_ENV would handle swapping out the imports in the context of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So then do I need a middle file that imports and exports the desired files based on the process.env.NODE_ENV value? `if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'firefox') { ... } else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'safari') { ... }`

Comment: i think if that's the case it'd be easier for you to make 2 webpack configs one for FF and one for safari and ship each independently